# Проблемы с загрузкой файлов на сервер

Tags: php, файлы

Написал простенький скрипт для загрузки файлов

```
$uploaddir="uploads/";
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],
 $uploaddir.$_FILES["filename"]["name"]))
{
echo ("Ваш файл успешно загружен <a href='".$uploaddir.basename($_FILES['filename']['name'])."'>here</a>.");

}
else
{
echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");}
 ?>
```

Но есть проблема когда загружаю файлы где присутствуют точки в названиях типа "1-урок. Введение. Yii framework" то после загрузки файла на сервер я не могу его скачать по ссылке,пишет что файл не найден,хотя в папке он присутствует....Вот что пишет

Not Found
 The requested URL /uploads/1-СѓСЂРѕРє. Р’РІРµРґРµРЅРёРµ. Yii framework.mp4 was not found on this server.

Заранее спасиббо!

Comment: А кириллица в названиях без точек как себя ведет?  Такие символы СѓСЂРѕРє. Р’РІРµРґРµРЅРёРµ присутствуют? Скорее всего проблема в кодировке.

Comment: нет без точек всё нормально.....Неподскажете, где можно поменять кодировку? может получится